# Is there a way to minimize my time during large file read in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, file

I am reading a `.tsv` file of 8,459,828 lines of data in my C++ project, line by line and making each line break into fragments of 9 different fields and insertion in a BST and getting approx. 30 minutes to read from ci7, 16 GB RAM and 3rd gen.

What is the easiest way to minimize the computational file processing time so I can have a really quick accessing from file?

```
  void filingData(){
    vector<string> temp;
    string line, word;

    fstream file("data.tsv", ios::in);
    if (file.is_open())
    {

        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            count++;
            temp.clear();

            stringstream str(line);

            while (getline(str, word, '\t')) 
            {
                temp.push_back(word);
            }

            int ascii;
            ascii = temp[8][0] - 65; // 26 trees are made for
            if (   ascii >= 0        // alphabetical separation so
               and ascii <= 25       // like my tree will have movies[0] will
                   )                 // have only the A named movies like that
            {
                movies[ascii]->insert( temp[0], temp[1], temp[2],
                                       temp[3], temp[4], temp[5],
                                       temp[6], temp[7], temp[8] );
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't tag C and C++ unless you are combining them or ask for differences. Also where is multi threading involved in your question?

Comment: OT: don't use magic numbers such as 65 and 25.

Comment: There is something i have heard till now that there are some forks in multithreading that will reduce my computational time? Thanks for guiding

Comment: I would assume file handling is not the issue in your code. Instead inserting the data into your tree is likely to take the most of your time.

Comment: Also what is `insert` and `movies`? That might be slow.

Comment: Parsing large ASCII files tends to be I/O and/or processing time intensive. It may be better to write a dedicated support program that reads the ASCII file, creates the BST, and exports in a binary form.  Then have your program exclusively read the binary file The trick is designing the binary format for sufficient accuracy and speed of reading.  Downsides include a need to recreate the binary file whenever the ASCII file changes (less issue if it changes relatively infrequently, since it only needs to be read once) and (if your program is long-running) force a re-read of the new binary file.

Comment: I assume that each line contains 9 strings that are related to one movie. You could combine them into a struct. Maybe some are numbers you could already convert to some integer before inserting. Then you would only need to pass 1 parameter to your insert function

Comment: @k200228IsmailAhmedAnsari *What is the easiest way to minimize the computational file processing time so I can have a really quick accessing from file.* -- I suggest you comment out the entire code where you are inserting, push_back, creating a temporary `stringstream`, etc. and only do the file reading.  Once you do that, how long did it take to read 8 million lines?  If it is just a few minutes, then the problem is not the reading of the file, it's the processing of the data.

Comment: If you think about executing something in parallel, you must ensure that your algorithm can be parallelized. Any access to common structures must be secured via semaphore/mutex. Normally the process of reading/writing files is not a good example for parallel execution.

Comment: @k200228IsmailAhmedAnsari Or better yet, a very simple `main` program: `int main() { std::ifstream file("data.tsv"); std::string line; while (std::getline(file, line)) {} }` -- How long did it take to run that program?

Comment: Why are you not using a database?

Comment: **Welcome to S/O** Have you done any performance-profiling, before asking question on StackOverflow? S/O is, since ever, based on a MCVE-formulations, kindly re-read the StackOverflow advice on how to best ask questions & prepare a REPRODUCIBLE ( i.e. working and running ) + MINIMAL ( i.e. not overly sized, if less big, yet still reproducible form & shape of the MCVE-code keeps demonstrating the issue ). Doing that, the knowledge sponsoring members of this great Community of Merit, can & will help to the best achievable goal ( not losing no ones expensive time in doubts, guestimates or alike )

Comment: Find a C++ profiler (I don't know much about C++ tooling, so I can't recommend a specific one), and let it measure which part of the program consumes the time. Then you know where to improve performance. How to improve that part (or to replace it with a different approach) is then the second step. Trying to optimize without profound measurements typically results in a waste of effort.

Comment: By the way, your program already contains an "optimization" by using 26 BSTs. Have you measured that this improves performance over a straightforward single-BST version?

Answer (score 0):

Based off the context you provided it sounds like this is a list of 8,459,828 movies (short text per line).

It should take no where near 30 minutes to read this input so the majority of time spent must be in the insert operation.

Here are a couple of suggestions:

- Try using a different BST implementation.
- You are currently bucketing on the first letter of the movie. If you bucket using the first 2 letters then each BST will be smaller and insertion time should go down.

Comment: Best BST implementations exist in databases, a tool you should be using in the first place.